# Python Dataframe: Create New Column Conditionally Using If Then Else Logic --> "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, ambiguous

I am using the following code to create a new column whose value is derived based on the values in two other columns of my Python dataframe.

```
# Create a list to store the data
MSP = []

for row in df_EVENT5_18['FLT']:
    if df_EVENT5_18['FLT'].str.contains('1234') & df_EVENT5_18['AR'].str.contains('ABC1'):
        MSP.append(29)
    elif (df_EVENT5_18['FLT'].str.contains('1234')) & (df_EVENT5_18['AR'].str.contains('ABC2')):
        MSP.append(25)
    else:
        MSP.append('')

# Create a new column from the list 
df_EVENT5_18['MSP'] = MSP
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you think you need a loop in pandas, check your code one more time.  One clue is that you have `for row in df_EVENT5_18['FLT']:`, but you never use `row`.

#### Find indicies that match a string

In this case we can simply use boolean evaluation to get the indices that we want to set:

```
has_flt_1234 = df_EVENT5_18['FLT'].str.contains('1234')
want_29 = has_flt_1234 & df_EVENT5_18['AR'].str.contains('ABC1')
want_25 = has_flt_1234 & df_EVENT5_18['AR'].str.contains('ABC2')
```

#### Setting values using boolean series

Then set the appropriate rows as desired:

```
df_EVENT5_18['MSP'][want_25] = '25'
df_EVENT5_18['MSP'][want_29] = '29'
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_EVENT5_18 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    FLT=['1234', '1234', '1235'],
    AR=['ABC1', 'ABC2', 'ABC1']
))

print(df_EVENT5_18)

has_flt_1234 = df_EVENT5_18['FLT'].str.contains('1234')
want_29 = has_flt_1234 & df_EVENT5_18['AR'].str.contains('ABC1')
want_25 = has_flt_1234 & df_EVENT5_18['AR'].str.contains('ABC2')

# Create a new column from the list
df_EVENT5_18['MSP'] = ''
df_EVENT5_18['MSP'][want_25] = '25'
df_EVENT5_18['MSP'][want_29] = '29'

print(df_EVENT5_18)
```

#### Results:

```
     AR   FLT
0  ABC1  1234
1  ABC2  1234
2  ABC1  1235

     AR   FLT MSP
0  ABC1  1234  29
1  ABC2  1234  25
2  ABC1  1235
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response.  the way you apply logic here is very interesting ... is there a way to do this with if-elif-else?

Comment: Of course there is.  But don't do that.  This will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
df[['new_col']] = df[['a','b'].apply(lambda (a,b) : pd.Series(your condition here),axis=1)
```